# Не грузится сцена в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал три сцены. 1 - меню игры. 2- игровые сцены.
Переход на игровую сцену осуществляю через GUI кнопку

```
...
 void OnGUI()
 {
GUI.skin = style;
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,10,420,170),"",start))
  {
  Application.LoadLevel ( 2 );
  }
...
```

В билде, как я знаю, отображается что-то вроде цифрового идентификатора сцены (ее порядковый номер). Соответственно этот номер (сцены) указал в скрипте.
После того, как построил игру и запустил ее, кнопка GUI не может загрузить игровую сцену "2" и игра просто зависает. В чем может быть причина?

В самом скрипте я пробовал указывать не номер сцены, а ее название. Не помогло. Такая же проблема. Менял сцены, которые можно загрузить. Тоже самое..

Использую Unity **4.2.0.f4**, игра на ПК.

---

Весь скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MM : MonoBehaviour {
public GUISkin style;
public GUIStyle start;
public GUIStyle history;
public GUIStyle Missions;
public GUIStyle Exit;
public AnimationClip a;
public GameObject As;

 void OnGUI()
 {
GUI.skin = style;
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,10,420,170),"",start))
  {
  Application.LoadLevel ( 2 );
  }
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,180,420,170),"",history))
  {
As.animation.Play(a.name);
  }
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,350,420,170),"",Missions))
  {
As.animation.Play(a.name);
  }

  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,520,420,170),"",Exit))
  {
  Application.Quit();
  }
}
```

А вот само меню игры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: могу посоветовать _никогда_ не писать цифру с номером сцены а писать по имени. Не с 0 ли нумеруются сцены в юнити? Попробуйте написать 1 вместо 2. Так же можно проверить в настройках проектах у какой сцены какой номер. Эта информация поезнее чем скрин меню.

Comment: В самом скрипте я пробовал указывать не номер сцены, а ее название. Не помогло. Такая же проблема. Меня сцены, которые можно загрузить. Тоже самое...

Comment: В самой юнити кнопка работает хорошо. А вот после билда она приводит игру к зависанию

Comment: Пока не совсем по теме...... какую версию Юнити используете? Если 5, там используется не `Application` а `SceneManager.LoadScene` .............и какой проект билдите? для веб, андройд или для чего? ...... А в логе что-то пишет?

Comment: а вы точно при билде поставили галочку чтобы сцена ушла в билд?

Comment: Использую Unity4.2.0.f4, игра на ПК.
В самой юнити все работает. После билда не загружается сцена, игра виснит.

Comment: галочку поставил

Comment: А что пишет `output_log.txt` ? у сбилженного проекта? Когда билдиться проект возникают какие-либо сообщения в консоли? Вообще в консоли юнити есть какие-то предупреждения?

Comment: Нету никаких ошибок консоли и вообще ничего. Все гладко.

Comment: Чудеса... хоть бери исходник и сам садись за отладку)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать имя сцены, а не её номер:

```
Application.LoadLevel("scene_first");
```

Без понятия где тут можно ошибиться, но вариантов несколько:

1.Имя сцены

2.Не добавляете сцену в билд

3.Не та сцена

4.Звезды не сошлись как надо, и уже никогда не сойдутся.

Comment: Он же написал в комментарии, что пробовал. Если только он наврал или ошибся в написании)

Comment: 0
голос против
accept
Имя сцены проверил. Сцена в билде есть Сцена точно та Звезды сами по себе) Все попробовал, что вы говорили, проблема в билде явно. Так все работает, стоит забилдить и не работает ничего... Всем спасибо за помощь. Не думал, что столько желающих будет помочь ;)

Answer (score 0):

Вообще на данный момент Application.LoadLevel(); помечен как Depricated, то есть как не желательный для использования. Он в принципе сейчас может вызывать краши и ошибки.

Попробуйте воспользоваться новым средством Scenemanager:
В начале вашего скрипта подключаете using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

В месте вызова сцены прописываете SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
Иными словами примерно так будет выглядеть ваш скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class MM : MonoBehaviour {
public GUISkin style;
public GUIStyle start;
public GUIStyle history;
public GUIStyle Missions;
public GUIStyle Exit;
public AnimationClip a;
public GameObject As;


 void OnGUI()
 {
GUI.skin = style;
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,10,420,170),"",start))
  {
  SceneManager.LoadScene(2);
  }
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,180,420,170),"",history))
  {
As.animation.Play(a.name);
  }
  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,350,420,170),"",Missions))
  {
As.animation.Play(a.name);
  }

  if(GUI.Button(new Rect(15,520,420,170),"",Exit))
  {
  Application.Quit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку. Кажется мой юнити не поддерживет. Поддерживало бы на Юнити 5. Или в другом проблема?
Assets/Standard Assets/Image Effects (Pro Only)/MM.cs(3,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEngine'. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: `SceneManager` для Юнити 5, у ТС Юнити 4.2